# como cancelar Alarmmanager

Tags: java, android

Hola he creado un sistema de notificaciones el cual cada cierto tiempo va a consultar si hay notas para mostrarlas y eso lo hace a través de un Alarmmanager que se queda en la cache en segundo plano ejecutándose. Eso lo hace perfecto, pero el problema es que cuando quiero que no siga trabajando no soy capaz de cancelar dicho Alarmmanager. Lo he intentado por activa y por pasiva pero no se como anularlo.

Aquí os dejo el código.

CODIGO DEL MAIN.

```
boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if(alarmRunning == false) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 59000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

CODIGO DE CIERRE DESDE OTRA ACTIVITY.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Espero que me podéis echar una mano y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Agregue esto (donde `a` es la actividad a eliminar), si tiene varios cree varios métodos

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceive.class);

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, a, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(sender);
```